# jQuery: multiple cycle slideshows with nav

Tags: jquery, html, slideshow

I'm trying to figure out how to implement multiple jQuery slideshows (with next and prev nav), as the slideshows will be added dynamically by the client I've used classes and tried to achieve something whereby it will find the next instance of the nav and use that to cycle the slideshow:

```
$('.text-page-slideshow').each(function(){
var $this = $(this);
    $this.cycle({
        fx: 'fade',  
        speed: 400,     
        timeout: 0,
        next: $this.next('.nav-next'),
        prev: $this.next('.nav-prev')
    });    
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle demo too: http://jsfiddle.net/ncknm/2/

It might just be something I'm missing, but for example I'm trying to find the next instance of `.nav-next` to use as the navigation for the relevant slideshow, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you will have to give unique identifier for each slideshow container, however, it shouldn't be problem, because page is created by server side script (just increment one var)

http://jsfiddle.net/ncknm/3/

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {



for(i=1;i<3;i++) { //you can easily get number from database, i hope

$('#slider'+i).cycle({
        fx: 'fade',  
        speed: 400,     
        timeout: 0,
        next: $('#slider'+i).next().children('.nav-next'),
       prev: $('#slider'+i).next().children('.nav-prev')
    });


}



});
```

P.S. -> $(this) inside cycle function doesn't reference desired div... that was problem.

Please try with this, if you don't want to dig in wp template files:

```
 jQuery.each($(".text-page-slideshow"), function(i) {

$(this).attr('id',"slider"+i);
$('#slider'+i).cycle({
        fx: 'fade',  
        speed: 400,     
        timeout: 0,
        next: $('#slider'+i).next().children('.nav-next'),
       prev: $('#slider'+i).next().children('.nav-prev')
    });

}); 


});
```

Comment: Thanks for that—great solution, although it doesn't quite work in this case, as the slideshows are being generated dynamically in wordpress I can't attach a unique ID to each, as much as I'd like to :(

Comment: Ah, so, Wordpress... well... please check updated answer above :)

Comment: THANK YOU! That's worked at charm :) I do have access to all the template files as I built the template, I was just after the least intrusive method to solve the problem and this is perfect, thanks again.